# OpenCV CompareHist of two images returns higher value than expected

Tags: c++, objective-c, opencv, image-processing

I implemented OpenCV CompareHist method in Objective-C to compare similarity of two images:

Image 1

[image: Image1]

and

Image 2

[image: Image2])

But it returns wrong result.

It returns **0.999971**, when I expect that it would be less than 0.9.

```
- (bool) someMethod:(UIImage *)image :(UIImage *)temp {

cv::Mat src_base, hsv_base;
cv::Mat src_test1, hsv_test1;

src_base = [self cvMatWithImage:image];
src_test1 = [self cvMatWithImage:temp];

cv::cvtColor(src_base, hsv_base, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
cv::cvtColor(src_test1, hsv_test1, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

int h_bins = 50; int s_bins = 60;
int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };

float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };

const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };

// Use the o-th and 1-st channels
int channels[] = { 0, 1 };


/// Histograms
cv::MatND hist_base;
cv::MatND hist_half_down;
cv::MatND hist_test1;
cv::MatND hist_test2;

calcHist( &hsv_base, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist_base, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
normalize( hist_base, hist_base, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX, -1, cv::Mat() );

calcHist( &hsv_test1, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist_test1, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
normalize( hist_test1, hist_test1, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX, -1, cv::Mat() );

double base_test1 = compareHist( hist_base, hist_test1, 0);

NSLog(@"%f", base_test1);

if (base_test1>0.9) {
    return true;
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it would be less than 0.9? The two images as some red color and white color. The shape dosen't effect the histogram

Comment: Because I want to assume that they are different. I am implementing Signature Authentication so I need that those images will be different

Comment: Do you mean that images will be similar because the colors and sizes are the same?

Comment: But like is said they it is not suppressing that they have a similar histograms they have the same colors and the thickness of the red lines is approximate the same so there histogram will be close. I think you need another way to to that like using the moments of each shape as a way to describe them. Have a look on Hu moments and matchShapes in http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look